# Mention of conversation with hiring manager in cover letter

Tags: job-search, applications, cover-letter

I took the first step and talked in person to the hiring manager of the position I am interested in. Should I mention the conversation and thank the hiring manager in the introduction of my cover letter?

Answer (score 6):

You could maybe name-drop it casually. "I'm sending you this letter as a response to my brief correspondence with X" or something of the sorts. I wouldn't make to big of a deal out of it.